# In UWP, how to transform from one image to another?

Tags: xaml, uwp, transform

TranslateTransform translates an element in x-y direction, ScaleTransform scales the transform based on a center point, RotateTransform & SkewTransform rotates & skews an UI Element. But how to transform one image to another image? None of the above seems to be helpful in this scenario. Suppose I have Key normal image and Key pressed image (of a Keyboard). I want to achieve the effect of keypressing animation, using the 2 images, using transform or any other means.

Comment: What do you expect the transformation to look like? Would it be sufficient to change the opacity of the top image (when you stack them) so the other image would appear slowly?

Comment: Check these classes `Storyboard/ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames/DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, using them you can have animation on the `Visibility` and `Opacity` properties of an Image, so when apply to the two images separately, you can hide/show them within an duration like 200 ms, thus having an transformation effect.

Comment: Or even easier, try the built-in [FadeIn/Fadeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.FadeInThemeAnimation#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_FadeInThemeAnimation__ctor) animation.

Comment: Fade In/Out animation - Changing Opacity using storyboards, that is what I have decided to implement. Very simple too. But, it does not give a keypress animation. It would only be simply a image change animation. There won't be any effect like morphing, real effect of pressing a key.

Comment: I found some relative [blog](https://www.cnblogs.com/dino623/p/UWP_Shape_PointAnimation.html) about morph animation that you could refer.

Comment: In old versions of windows all the press animation would do is darken the left and top border sides and lighten the right and bottom border sides. Again: you have to be more clear about what you want exactly.